# Python Pandas select rows by a string condition and then update the relevant column values

Tags: python, pandas, split, contains

I have a dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'month':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'flavour':['strawberry1%aw','strawberry','banana','banana','strawberry','strawberry','banana1%a11','banana1%20']})
```

I want to remove the string after % in the column flavour:

```
sep = "%"
mask = d.flavour.str.contains(sep)
d.loc[mask,'_id'].map(lambda x: x.split(sep, 1)[0])
```

How can I ensure these values are updated in the original dataframe (s)? The expected final dataframe as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is `d` not your dataframe?

Comment: d is an example of a dataframe..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us using `split`

```
d.flavour=d.flavour.apply(lambda x :x.split('%')[0])
d
Out[111]: 
       flavour  month
0  strawberry1      1
1   strawberry      2
2       banana      3
3       banana      4
4   strawberry      5
5   strawberry      6
6      banana1      7
7      banana1      8
```

Comment: He expect replace `month` with `%`, no just append `month` at the end of each item!

Comment: That's definetly the better answer, no need to generate a mask.

Comment: @Wen I no sure, but his expect data different with the image!

Comment: Might as well use the vectorized accessor: `flavour.str.split("%").str[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sep = "%"
mask = d.flavour.str.contains(sep)
```

Update the values back to the original dataframe (d) by using 'mask' and the column name as follows:

```
d.loc[mask,'flavour']=d.loc[mask,'flavour'].map(lambda x: x.split(sep, 1)[0])
```

Comment: This answer is currently flagged as low-quality. Thanks for the answer though. Suggest you add some explanation too, so others can understand easily.